# Index pixels to color certain location of pictures

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, while-loop, pixel

I'm creating a method that takes two parameters with 2 indexes a start and an end that takes a location of the picture being edited and turn those pixels to a different color. Using a while loop to index start and end.

The problem I'm having is I'm only a getting a really small portion to change color:

Don't mind some of the code that is commented out. I was trying a bunch of different things.

```
public void negative(int start, int end)
{
    Pixel[] pixelArray = this.getPixels(); //pixelarray index
    Pixel pixel = null;
    // int height = this.getHeight();
    //int paintPoint = height / 2;
    //int width = this.getWidth();
    int i = 0;
    int red, green, blue = 0;
    // int x = 0;
    Pixel topPixel = null;
    Pixel bottomPixel = null;
    //int startY;
    //int startX;
    int y = start;
    int x = end;
    //int count;
    while( y < this.getHeight())
    {
        y++;
        while (x < this.getWidth()) //loops through index
        {
          pixel = this.getPixel(x,y);
          red = pixel.getRed();
          green = pixel.getGreen();//collects color green
          blue = pixel.getBlue();//collects color blue 
          Color negColor = new Color( 255 - red, 255 - green, 255 - blue);//sets new values of pixels
          pixel.setColor(negColor);

          x++;
          //count = count + 1;
          i++;//indexes continuing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A picture is 2D yet you are treating it as 1D (notice after once through your inner x loop it never is reset to its min value).  If you wish to color an arbitrary rectangle within a given photo the parms should include two points :  minx, miny  and maxx maxy   then your pair of 2D loops visits each point in that region line by line.

```
// do sanity checks on your parms 

if (this.getWidth() < maxx) {
    maxx = this.getWidth();
}
if (this.getHeight() < maxy) {
    maxy = this.getHeight();
}
if (minx < 0) { 
    minx = 0;
}
if (miny < 0) { 
    miny = 0;
}


for (y = mixy; y < maxy; y++) {

    for (x = mixx; x < maxx; x++) {

        // now your have valid x and y values
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I solved the problem a while back. I was not allowed to use a  for loop, and we were instructed to use a while loop.